# how to compare a unicode string in model field and choices? django

Tags: python, django, if-statement, unicode, compare

I am not sure which part I am doing wrong but somehow I am trying to compare two values and I am 100% sure they matches but somehow code would not execute.

Let's say I have this model (please forgive for a bit typos for models and field names)

```
class TestOne(models):
    gender = models.Charfield(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

my choices

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (("MALE", "MALE"), ("FEMALE", "FEMALE"))
```

I am so sure my `gender` field is `MALE` for the object so I am doing this statement as check that if it's `MALE` do something.

```
if a.gender is `MALE`:
    # do something here
```

but it never reaches it as true.  I checked `a.gender` is a `unicode` type so I even did `str(a.gender)` to make sure it's also a string but still no luck.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

P.S. I did a print with `a.gender` and made sure that the output is `MALE`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do:

```
if a.gender is 'MALE':
# equivalent to:
# id(a.gender) == id('MALE')
```

Do instead:

```
if a.gender == 'MALE':
```

The `'is'` keyword checks object identity, i.e. whether two variables/objects reference the identical memory address. `'=='` checks equality as defined in the class' `'__eq__'` method, which in your case will perform the expected string comparison.

Check [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thx thx, can I say is is the same as triple  = in JavaScript?